# PNG image won't show in IE7 or Firefox but works in Opera

Tags: browser, png

I got a webservice which creates a PNG-file and returns a link to it.
Then this graphic is used by a website (ASP.NET).

IE7 & Firefox 3 can't show this image but in Opera 9.5 it works fine.

Did anyone run across the same problem before?

Edit:
Content-type is set to image/png.
The image is created with the library from a 3rd party vendor which is not available to the public.

Any chance to check the png-file for compliance to the standard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the png wasn't rendered with the right dpi settings. A subtle bug that emerged after some months.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, both IE7 and FF can display PNG images. As it seems your PNG is not fully compliant to the rendering engines of these browsers (or to the standard?).

It is hard to tell where the problem lies exactly without knowing how the image was created. Which lib are you using? Do you have sample code?

EDIT (After reading the comment by Yuval A): 
You could also check whether the HTTP response sent by your web server has the correct content type set for PNG images. This might be needed by browsers to display the image correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Check how your web service is "returning the link" to it.
Is it represented correctly on the HTML response? (i.e. in an **IMG** tag with a correct **src**?)